# How to get correlation between Variables and Principal Components in Python

Tags: python, pca

I am using PCA for reducing variables. I want to get the correlation of each variable to the final PCs. What I want is the Adjusted Rsquare of each variable with each PC. This will have identify which variables are most closely related to a particular PC and highly uncorrelated with others.

Sklean gives eigen values, eigen vectors, explained variance ratio. Is there any property through which we can get the correlation of variables with PC

```
genes = ['gene' + str(i) for i in range (1,101)]

wt = ['wt' + str(i) for i in range (1,6)]
ko = ['ko' + str(i) for i in range (1,6)]

data = pd.DataFrame(columns = [*wt,*ko], index = genes)

for gene in data.index:
    data.loc[gene,'wt1':'wt5'] = np.random.poisson(lam = rd.randrange(10,1000), size =5)
    data.loc[gene,'ko1':'ko5'] = np.random.poisson(lam = rd.randrange(10,1000), size =5)

x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

pca = PCA(0.95)

principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(x)

corr = pca.components_

features = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

matrix = pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a start, you can calculate it directly:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[[np.corrcoef(data[c],principalComponents[:,n])[1,0] 
               for n in range(pca.n_components_)] for c in data],
             columns=[0,1],
             index = data.columns)
```

Comment: There is a big difference in PCA using Python statsmodel and SAS Varclus Procedure. I used the following codes in Python and SAS


Python:

from statsmodels.multivariate.pca import PCA

pc = PCA(x, standardize=True, method='svd', ncomp=2)

factors = pc.factors

coefficients = pc.coeff

eigenvalues = pc.eigenvals

loading = pc.loadings

SAS:

proc varclus data = raw_data maxeigen = 1;
var wt1-wt5 ko1-ko5;
run;

Comment: It's very hard to read code in comments like this. Please edit it back into your question.